# How do I make the responsive navigation stack vertically on the small screen or landscape orientation on smartphones (using Bootstrap 4 alpha 2)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, django-bootstrap4

Here is my CSS and HTML for that section:

```css
@media (min-width:544px) {
  .navbar-toggler {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
  }
  .nav-responsive li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-item {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
  
  
  
}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (orientation: landscape)
{
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row; /* This will override the flex-direction: column */
}





}
```

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
&#9776;</button>  
    
    

<div class="collapse navbar-expand-lg navbar-toggleable-sm" id="menu">
    

    
<ul class="navbar-nav nav-responsive pull-md-right">

<li class="nav-item"><a href="https://christymlittle.com/" class="nav-link" title="">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="about" class="nav-link" title="">About</a></li>

<li class="nav-item"><a href="work" class="nav-link" title="">Work</a>

</li>
    
<li class="nav-item"><a href="contact" class="nav-link" title="">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

Update: This site won't let me insert a screenshot and I don't have this on a live site at the moment. The simulator will show the menu as vertical on landscape view on smartphones, but the top link sticks out more to the left than the other links. This continues on the larger screens, despite the override in the large breakpoint.

Comment: I realized that I forgot the px in my small breakpoint in my post. I tested it again, and the problem remains the same.

Comment: Can you please combine the snippets so we can take a better look?

Comment: Hey Christy. You need more rep to insert screnshots. However, you could use codesandbox.io or similar to recreate what you have on local. Looking at your code, all you need to put in the [mcve] is the (HTML) markup and the CSS (don't forget to include all the CSS files that apply to your example, not only your custom CSS) - you can add any number of CSS files to a snippet (either here or on codesanbox).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace the `navbar` of your `<ul>` element with `navbar-nav`, and add the `navbar-expand-lg` class to your `<div>`.

The `navbar-nav` class creates the vertical stack, and `navbar-expand-lg` from the parent element ensures it displays horizontally on a large screen.

See the following snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
    @media (min-width:544px) {
        .navbar-toggler {
            float: right;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
        }

        .nav-responsive li {
            display: block;
        }

        .nav-item {
            list-style: none;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
        .navbar-nav {
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column; /* This will override the flex-direction: column */
        }
    }


</style>
<body>

<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
&#9776;</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-expand-lg navbar-toggleable-sm" id="menu">
  <ul class="navbar-nav nav-responsive pull-md-right">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" id="current" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="work" class="nav-link">Work</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

From the console showing Bootstrap styles:

Small screen:

```css
.navbar-nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Large screen:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row; /* This will override the flex-direction: column */
}
}
```

Comment: So, the override for the large breakpoint helps, but the responsive menu on the small screen still shows as horizontal.

Comment: @Christy Is it horizontal for both portrait and landscape? Or is it only landscape?

Comment: Just landscape.

Comment: Update: The good news is that the menu is more vertical, but I notice on some smartphone types in my simulator, the top link of the menu sticks out a bit to the left as though it is looking to float with the next link down.

Comment: @Christy Thanks for the update. Can you please update your question with a screenshot so I can have a better look?